# Octobercms - CSRF Protection on a form to preventing multiple submission

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, octobercms

I have a component with a form and then code to handle the submission.  The problem is, if I spam the button it will submit the form multiple times.  A solution to this would be to add a disabled state via Javascript to prevent the user from doing this.

From a security reason I do not want this to happen at all and prevent server side.  I have a token and in the config I have CSRF enabled

```
'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
```

Here is my form

```
{{ form_open({ request: 'onSubmit' }) }}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="subject_name">Subject's name</label>
                <input id="subject_name" name="subject_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Postcode</label>
                <input id="postcode"  name="postcode" class="form-control input-md" type="text" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-gold pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Request Job</button>
            </div>

 </form>
```

and in the generated html

Handler/ Session / Token

```
<input name="_handler" type="hidden" value="onSubmit">
<input name="_session_key" type="hidden" value="7Eg9bK4pcT2NOgWwUS0UFUckjkSMRC1UDBkBhPwO">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="00nbkK3EAo2I8WGWSh85qkMjHYig6aldrd3oe8HZ">
```

Then in my components code

```
public function onSubmit()
{

    $name = post('subject_name');
    $postcode = post('postcode');

    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token')) 
    { 

        /* Invalid token */ 
        return print('Token invalid');

    }

    $job = new Job;
    $job = $job->name = $name;
    $job = $job->postcode = $postcode;
    $job->save();

}
```

Yet I spam the submit button and it will execute multiple times.  How can I add the ability to only execute once?

Comment: CSRF protection has nothing to do with multiple submissions. If you just want to stop multiple submissions, just set a session value, like: `Session::set('form_posted', true);` in the end of the method and then add a check in the beginning that checks if it's set or not. It it's set, don't do anything.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Well not really if I could force a new token on each request.  What do you suggest I do for stopping it submitting multiple times?

Comment: I'm not a fan of refreshing the tokens on each request since it can lead to annoying issues for the users. Example: A user opens your site. Then click on a link and open it in a new tab. Then, then go back to the first tab and try to post the form, but the CSRF is now invalid since you've refreshed it in the other tab.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson good point.  Is session to best way to go about then?  Just thinking if they wanted to submit another request in the same session they won't be able to do so.  I just want to stop it executing multiple times in the space of a minute or so.  Would it come down to setting a timestamp?

Comment: That should definitely work. If the session doesn't exist or if the timestamp is more then x minutes old, handle the submitted info, otherwise, return some error message or something. It won't stop them from posting it several times from different browsers and/or in incognito mode though. But that's a tougher nut to crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a loader

https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/loader

```
<div class="loading-indicator-container">

    <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" data-load-indicator="Saving..." class="btn btn-lg btn-gold pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Request Job</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous solutions to what you want done.

My suggestion the most eloquent solution is a redirect or an ajax update. Communicate with your users by replacing the form with a message that says your "Request has been submitted. Thank you." This will stop them from being able to spam the submit button.

You could do something with the session like advised by Magnus. Make sure to include a timestamp so it can be removed after some time.